# How do rainy days affect plant growth?

Tags: story-of-seasons

You can water your plants twice a day, this increases how quickly they'll grow. On rainy days, your plants are watered for you (by the rain, obviously).

I remember that, in *Tale of Two Towns*, weather could change midday. If it rained in the morning or in the afternoon, you could get credit for two waterings. But if it rained the entire day, you'd only get credit for one watering.

*Story of Seasons*, on the other hand, has a "one weather all day" system. How does this affect plant growth? Do you get credit for two waterings on rainy days or just one?

Comment: I would guess it counts for 2, but this will need to take some science.

Comment: I'm pretty sure A New Beginning only counted it as one watering, so my guess is it only counts once in Story of Seasons as well, since they are fairly similar.

Comment: I completely forgot about the twice a day watering mechanic that was introduced a few games back...

Answer (score 1):

According to a post in [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/734977-story-of-seasons/71571219), a rainy day will only credit you with one watering.

> It counts as a single watering. So always make sure you have time for the maximum number of days for your crop before the end of the month. You don't want to get screwed because it rained a lot and made the crops wilt by the season change.

Another post [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/734977-story-of-seasons/71650717) seems to confirm this behavior:

> as it is, rain is sort of a disadvantage. I mean, on a regular day you can double water for your crops to grow faster but when it rains you can't.